# How to find gaps in dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as

```
DATE    LEAVEDAYS   NXTWRKDAYS
2014-07-01  No  NULL
2014-07-02  No  NULL
2014-07-03  No  NULL
2014-07-04  No  NULL
2014-07-05  Yes NULL
2014-07-06  Yes NULL
2014-07-07  Yes NULL
2014-07-08  No  NULL
2014-07-09  Yes NULL
2014-07-10  Yes NULL
2014-07-11  No  NULL
```

The output will be

```
DATE        LEAVEDAYS   NXTWRKDAYS
2014-07-01  No      2014-07-02
2014-07-02  No      2014-07-03
2014-07-03  No      2014-07-04
2014-07-04  No      2014-07-05
2014-07-05  Yes     2014-07-08
2014-07-06  Yes     2014-07-08
2014-07-07  Yes     2014-07-08
2014-07-08  No      2014-07-09 
2014-07-09  Yes     2014-07-11
2014-07-10  Yes     2014-07-11
2014-07-11  No      2014-07-12
```

As can be figure out that after 2014-07-04, the next working day was '2014-07-08' and henceforth the output after 2014-07-05 was 2014-07-08.
after 2014-07-10, the next working day was '2014-07-11' and henceforth the output after 2014-07-10 was 2014-07-11

**Script**

```
declare @t table([DATE] DATE,LEAVEDAYS Varchar(10),NXTWRKDAYS DATE)
insert into @t Values
('2014-07-01','No',NULL),
('2014-07-02','No',NULL),
('2014-07-03','No',NULL),
('2014-07-04','No',NULL),
('2014-07-05','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-06','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-07','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-08','No',NULL),
('2014-07-09','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-10','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-11','No',NULL)

select *
from @t
```

Comment: Shouldn't the next working day for `2014-07-04` be `2014-07-08`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this query, hope it helps you:

**Your create table and insert script:**

```
declare @t table([DATE] DATE,LEAVEDAYS Varchar(10),NXTWRKDAYS DATE)
insert into @t Values
('2014-07-01','No',NULL),
('2014-07-02','No',NULL),
('2014-07-03','No',NULL),
('2014-07-04','No',NULL),
('2014-07-05','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-06','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-07','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-08','No',NULL),
('2014-07-09','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-10','Yes',NULL),
('2014-07-11','No',NULL)
```

**Required Output:**

```
SELECT 
     t.date AS Date,
     t.leavedays AS LeaveDays, 
     CASE WHEN t.LEAVEDAYS = 'No' THEN DATEADD(day,1, t.DATE) 
          WHEN t.LEAVEDAYS = 'Yes' THEN (Select top 1 t1.date from @t t1 WHERE t1.date > t.DATE and t1.LEAVEDAYS = 'No' ORDER BY t1.date) 
          ELSE null END AS NxtWorkingDay
FROM @t t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using `APPLY`and `TOP`:

```
SELECT
    t.[DATE],
    t.LEAVEDAYS,
    NXTWRKDAYS = x.[DATE]
FROM @t t
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 [DATE]
    FROM @t
    WHERE 
        [DATE] > t.[DATE]
        AND LEAVEDAYS = CASE WHEN t.LEAVEDAYS = 'YES' THEN 'NO' ELSE LEAVEDAYS END          
) x
```